# Continuous Functional- $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ Definition Of Limit

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Maybe this is a trivial question, but to make sure:

Given a continuous functional $f:X\to \mathbb{F}$, when $X$ is a linear space and $\mathbb{F}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, can we use $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity? i.e, can we say that $\forall x\in X$

$\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists \delta>0$ s.t if $||x-y||<\delta$, $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$

?

Comment: What are $X$ and $\Bbb F$?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: The $\epsilon$-$\delta$ characterization of continuity holds in any metric space. If your space $X$ is a $\textbf{normed}$ linear space then it holds.

Comment: and if the metric is not induced by norm?

Comment: Also unless youre thinking of uniform continuity please fix the point, say, $x_2$ prior to the rest of the $\epsilon$ definition

Comment: @user what do you mean? The property holds more generally in metric spaces (which may or may not be normed linear spaces). Every norm is a metric.

Comment: ok, I understand, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not all vector spaces admits norms. For those that do, such a norm induces a metric where you may use $\epsilon$-$\delta$, and while two different norms in the same space give rise to different metrics, they are necessarily similar enough to always agree on which functions are continuous.

If the vector space has no norm, then there is no metric that plays well with the linear structure. There are, of course, other metrics, as any set of points may be endowed with some metric to make it a metric space.

Comment: BTW using \|x\| for the norm instead of ||x|| is easier to read : $\|x\|$ compared to $||x||$.